# How to open a terminal window and execute a customer program in java

Tags: java, linux, process, terminal, runtime.exec

I want to open a new terminal window and execute my program in java code. So I use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-terminal -x /path/to/my/program arg1 arg2");
```

This is work fine in Ubuntu but unfortunately it is not work in CentOS, the problem is that the terminal window closed immediately.

I have search many time in stackoverflow but could not find out a solution. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What terminal emulator/desktop environment are you trying to do this for/under?

Comment: The newer alternative ProcessBuilder covers some of the brittleness of exec.

Comment: 1) There are common mistakes made when creating new processes - as detailed in [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  The article is the *first* thing to check if a process fails.  Implement *all* the tips, and even if doing so does not make the process work, it will provide much more detailed information on why it failed.  

2) Use a `ProcessBuilder` to construct the process. 3) For more reliable results, make the `String` based arguments into a `String[]`.

Comment: does anything unusual happen if you enter it on the command line directly yourself?

Comment: in the shell, what is the output of **`type gnome-terminal`** in Ubuntu and the CentOS machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of you. I have found the problem that is when I copy my program to CentOS the execution permission is missed so the terminal can't execute it and then dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    Process pr =new ProcessBuilder("gnome-terminal", "-e", "pathToScript/script.sh").start();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```